# MongoDB aggregating data

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, lookup, lookup-tables

when I am running code from Mongodb [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to use pipeline in the $lookup
I am getting an error that **let is not supported**. How to use let: { <var_1>: , …, <var_n>:  } inside of $lookup.

Error:

[image: Error]

Code:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup:
         {
           from: "warehouses",
           let: { order_item: "$item", order_qty: "$ordered" },
           pipeline: [
              { $match:
                 { $expr:
                    { $and:
                       [
                         { $eq: [ "$stock_item",  "$$order_item" ] },
                         { $gte: [ "$instock", "$$order_qty" ] }
                       ]
                    }
                 }
              },
              { $project: { stock_item: 0, _id: 0 } }
           ],
           as: "stockdata"
         }
    }
])
```

Comment: what is the version of the mongodb?

Comment: @varman mongodb version:3.6.0